# How do you modify a variable that's a value in a dictionary when calling that variable by its key?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
n = 3

d = {'x':n}

d['x'] += 1

print(n)
```

When I run it, I get

```
3
```

How do I make n = 4?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, at least, not in any simple way.

The issue is very similar when you're just dealing with two variables bound to the same object. If you rebind one of them with an assignment, you will not see the new value through the other variable:

```
a = 3
b = a
a += 1 # binds a to a new integer, 4, since integers are immutable
print(b) # prints 3, not 4
```

One exception is if you are not binding a new value to the variable, but instead modifying a mutable object in-place. For instance, if instead of `1` you has a one-element list `[1]`, you could replace the single value without creating a new list:

```
a = [3]
b = a
a[0] += 1 # doesn't rebind a, just mutates the list it points to
print(b[0]) # prints 4, since b still points to the same list as a
```

So, for your dictionary example you could take a similar approach and have `n` and your dictionary value be a list or other container object that you modify in-place.

Alternatively, you could store the variable name `"n"` in your dictionary and then rather than replacing it in your other code, you could use for a lookup in the `globals` dict:

```
n = 3
d = {"x": "n"} # note, the dictionary value is the string "n", not the variable n's value
globals()[d["x"]] += 1
print(n) # this actually does print 4, as you wanted
```

This is very awkward, of course, and only works when `n` is a global variable (you can't use the nominally equivalent call to `locals` in a function, as modifying the dictionary returned by `locals` doesn't change the local variables). I would not recommend this approach, but I wanted to show it can be done, if only badly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class to contain the data values to enable additions. Basically you are creating a mutable object which *acts* as an integer.
It is a work around, but lets you accomplish what you want.

Note, that you probably need to override a few more Python operators to get full coverage:

```
class MyInt(object):
    val = 0
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
    def __iadd__(self,val):
        self.val = self.val + val
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.val)
n = MyInt(3)

print(n)
d = {'x':n}

d['x'] += 1

print(n)
```